Error when creating an EF under MF on smart card
I am new to ISO 7816 smart card programming. I am trying to create an EF under the MF. I can succesfully select the MF but there is an error creating the EF. These are the APDUs and responses.

00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00 is for selecting the MF and 00 E0 00 00 09 62 07 82 01 01 83 02 3F 01 is for creating an EF. The latter command is returning the error 6A 80 : Wrong parameter(s) P1-P2. Incorrect parameters in the data field. I cannot figure out what is the error in the data field.

From a short glance to my ancient comand table, you seem to have not specified, how big you want the created file to be, which for a transparent file needs to be specified in DO with tag 80.
Note, that smart cards typically are restricted to a very basic memory management, so you have to allocate the corresponding space for the EF at creation time.

I am trying to specify this with the APDU 00 E0 00 00 09 62 0B 80 02 00 30 82 01 38 83 02 3F 00 00 but getting error Can't get info: Transaction failed

@Noor: possibly a typo, but 3F00 is the reserved ID for the MF, which is unlikely to be creatable by Create File, there (as for other DFs) also 80 is not correct. I suggest to change fewer things at the same time.

agree for the 3F00, will change that, for 80, what is the issue, i read that it is 2 bytes, that is why 80 is followed by 02 and 0030 is the file size

00 E0 00 00 0C 62 0A 80 01 02 82 01 38 83 02 2F 01 00 superb, i've tried this and it works

i'm new to programming on smart cards, wanted to know, is there a way to reset the card directly, that is delete MF and its contents

@Noor: Yes there is a way to do this, unfortunately it is not standardized, therefore each card type will require different commands.
